# Magento controller only executing once - cannot disable cache

Tags: magento2, cache, controllers, full-page-cache

I have a controller that only executes once after the cache is cleared. After that the response is always the same - cache is there instead of a new execution.

The class is extends\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action:

`class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

What can I do inside this controller to get rid of the cache activity?

This is not related to any block, meaning that it cannot be done via xml cacheable=false option.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure that cache comes from controller side ? try to stop loading layout and check the controller result again

Answer (score 0):

You can add cache control header inside your controller

```
/**
     * This action render random number for each request
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
        //We are using HTTP headers to control various page caches (varnish, fastly, built-in php cache)
        $page->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);

        return $page;
    }
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html